# What are expenses that must be kept in mind when investing in the stock market?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, starting-out-investing

I live in the UK and am gathering information about stock market investment. I am not interested in day trading at this time. I became interested in stocks due to reading about news related to Tesla and their stocks. I want to have a decent understanding of the stock market and how to use it before I put any money in.

At this time I have a few questions which are as follows. I am trying to get answers to these from a UK perspective:

1. What are the costs to buy and sell shares e.g cost to register an account, make transactions e.t.c?
2. How to know when to buy and when not to buy?
3. How to know when to sell and when not to sell?
4. Is the only option to buy from NASDAQ that only exists online or can one buy stocks from Tokyo or New York stock exchanges as well while being in UK?

The most important questions are:

5. How much tax do I pay when earning money from selling shares in UK?
6. Is tax also paid if I just transfer shares to someone else who sells them and I get nothing from it?

Comment: There are too many questions to be answerable here; you should break these down into several smaller, more related questions, as separate posts. Questions 2&3 are off topic for this site [specific action advice isn't really possible]. Question 5 & 6 would be hard to answer without more information.

Answer (score 3):

1. Varies depending on platform and the other charges they're making, but could be anything from free to £5-£10.  This list of online brokers is invaluable for comparing the various platforms available: https://monevator.com/compare-uk-cheapest-online-brokers/
2. (& 3).  If you're really interested in "investing" rather than "trading", you shouldn't be too interested in this.  You should be more interested in the topic of asset allocation, and then the buying and selling follows in response to maintaining your asset allocation.  And your asset allocation should be determined by your investment goals and tolerance for risk.  There are several good pieces on Monevator on the topic; start with https://monevator.com/asset-allocation-investment-goals/ and google for the others.
3. Most online brokers support trading on international markets.  (For example, here's II's information on the topic: https://www.ii.co.uk/investing-with-ii/international-investing ).  Alternatively you can buy funds/ETFs/investment trusts on the UK market which then invest in those foreign markets for you.
4. If you invest in an tax sheltered account (an ISA or a SIPP), gains and dividends are tax free.  Outside of those in a regular dealing account you'll have to worry about taxes if the income and gains exceed the relevant thresholds.
5. Transferring shares to anyone except your spouse triggers a "capital event" and you'd be liable to pay tax on gains made while you'd held them, if they were large enough, just as if you were selling those shares yourself and then giving the recipient the cash.  There can also be inheritance tax implications if you die in the next 7 years and then the value might still be considered partially part of your estate.